# JavaScript não aceita valor da variável

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Estou tentando fazer uma função para chamar uma GRID que será diferente dependendo do parâmetro que eu passar. Esta é a função:

```
$JQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/main/conciliacao/gera-colunas/tabela/<?php echo $tabela ?>",
        success: function(data, st) {
            criaGrid(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Erro ao retornar os valores das colunas");
        }
    });
});

function criaGrid(colM) {
    $JQuery("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
        url: "/main/conciliacao/gera-grid/processo/<?php echo $processo ?>/tabela/<?php echo $tabela ?>/id/<?php echo $id ?>",
        datatype: "json",
        colModel: [ colM ],
        viewrecords: true, 
        width: 780,
        height: 200,
        rowNum: 30,
        pager: "#jqGridPager"
    });
}
```

Meu problema é que a variável colM tem o que eu preciso para criar as colunas da grid, mas se eu chamar ela no *colModel:* a função não reconhece o valor da variável.

O que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: `console.log(colM)` retorna o que?

Comment: Retorna { label: 'id', name: 'id', width: 75 }, que é o que eu preciso. Se eu copiar o que vem no console.log() e colar no código funciona perfeitamente, mas se ficar na variável não

Comment: Onde exatamente está dando este erro? Dentro de `criaGrid`?

Comment: Isso, dentro do `criaGrid` na parte `colModel: [ colM ],`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você olhar a [documentação do plugin](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options), verá que `colModel` não espera uma array como você está passando, e sim um objeto. Você pode passar `colM` diretamente, sem embrulhar numa array:

```
function criaGrid(colM) {
    $JQuery("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
        url: "/main/conciliacao/gera-grid/processo/<?php echo $processo ?>/tabela/<?php echo $tabela ?>/id/<?php echo $id ?>",
        datatype: "json",
        colModel: colM,
        viewrecords: true, 
        width: 780,
        height: 200,
        rowNum: 30,
        pager: "#jqGridPager"
    });
}
```

Porém essa propriedade `table` que você tem no seu `colM` não é uma das opções válidas para `colModel`, não sei bem qual é a sua intenção com esse valor.

---

Quanto ao seu comentário de que passando a variável ele não aceita, pode ser porque seu JSON não está sendo interpretado como tal. Para resolver isso, informe na chamada ajax que o retorno será um JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/main/conciliacao/gera-colunas/tabela/<?php echo $tabela ?>",
    dataType: "json", // <--- aqui
    success: function(data, st) {
        criaGrid(data);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Erro ao retornar os valores das colunas");
    }
});
```